# Input error when trying to set an integer in mysql Database. (IllegalArgumentException: null PK instance)

Tags: java, mysql, database

I am trying to input some data into a mysql database. However, when I try to run the program I get this error:`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An instance of a null PK has been incorrectly provided for this find opertaion`, I suspect this is due to `event.setPriority(prist);` however I am not experienced enough to tell why and how I can fix it.

```
 try{ Calendar duedate = Calendar.getInstance();
 Listevent event = new Listevent(); 
 TimeTableAddEvent tb = new TimeTableAddEvent();

 int prist = Integer.parseInt(PriTxt.getText());


 event.setName(EventTxt.getText());
 event.setDescription(DescTxt.getText());
 event.setPriority(prist);
 event.setDateofdue(DateTxt.getDate());

 EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("TimeEven DataBasePU");
 ListeventJpaController lejc = new ListeventJpaController((emf));
 lejc.create(event);
 }catch(Exception e){

     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
 }
```

Comment: what does the value of `prist` show up to be? What about `PriTxt`?

Comment: priTxt is a text field's in put in String. Prist is my effort to try and change the String value of PriTxt into an integer. The Value of prist will be a whole number.

Comment: check it. The exception says otherwise.